# Отобразить содержимое страницы по ссылке WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Вот код

```
<?
    $activeCity = do_shortcode( '[city]' );  // этот результат выдает плагин BelingoGeo
    if($activeCity == "Москва") {
        $link = get_field('main_p_moskow','options');
    }
    if($activeCity == "Санкт Петербург") {
        $link = get_field('main_p_saint_p','options');
    }
    if($activeCity == "Иркутск") {
        $link = get_field('main_p_irk','options');
    }
?>
```

Зная ссылку на страницу определенного города мне нужно вывести ее содержимое. Как это можно сделать средствами WordPress?

Comment: [url_to_postid()](https://wp-kama.com/function/url_to_postid), а имея ID, можете получить что угодно.

Comment: $id = url_to_postid( $link ); Вот ID есть. А как получить весь html страницы по этому ID?

Comment: `весь html страницы` -- уточните что Вы под этим подразумеваете. Если нужен `post_content`, то `$my_post = get_post($id); $content = apply_filters('the_content', $my_post->post_content;);` можете попробовать и короче `get_post_field('post_content', $id);`